# Return type of bitwise operation in C

Tags: c, type-conversion

I have an int (32) value `Val` packed in form

```
----------------------------------------
| 32-XXXXXXXXX-16 | 15-short-int-val-0 |
----------------------------------------
```

When extracting the short integer value from this `Val` if I do the operation

```
short temp = Val & 0x0000FFFF;
```

What is will be the return type of the operation `Val & 0x0000FFFF` ? Do I need to type cast the value to `(short)(Val & 0x0000FFFFF)` to have correct data stored in `temp`?

The doubt arises since I assume hex numbers are inherently treated as unsigned integers.

How is the above operation different from doing

```
short temp = Val & 0xFFFF;
```

Comment: `&` not logical but bitwise operator AND!, if you wants to return `short` just give return type `short`, if you wants to `return Val & 0x0000FFFF;` return type should be `int` because bit wise operator will auto promote result to `int`

Comment: Sorry will make that correction.

Comment: return type short would do.

Comment: As mentioned my intention is to save value in short variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume `32-bit` `int`, `16-bit` `short` and `8-bit` `char`.

```
short temp = Val & 0x0000FFFF;
```

`Val` is of type `int`. `0x0000FFFF` which is the same as `0xFFFF` is of type `int` as well.

The expression `Val & 0x0000FFFF` is then also of type `int` and is implicitly converted to `short` at initialization of `temp` object.

So:

> What is will be the return type of the operation Val & 0x0000FFFF ?

See above, `int`.

> Do I need to type cast the value to (short)(Val & 0x0000FFFFF) to have correct data stored in temp?

See above, no as the expression is implicitly converted to `short` at initialization of `temp` object.

> The doubt arises since I assume hex numbers are inherently treated as unsigned integers.

This is a wrong asssumption as here `0x0000FFFF` is of signed type `int`.

Comment: Implicit typecasting will take care assigning the sign correctly ? E.g. assume Val = 0xFFFF ? though I can verify this by executing will Val be treated as -1 or 32767 ? Please help understand the type casting.

Comment: @Bleamer The implicit conversion here means `short temp = Val & 0x0000FFFF;` and `short temp = (short) (Val & 0x0000FFFF);` are equivalent declarations. C says the conversion from `int` to `short` is implementation defined if the `int` value cannot be represented in `short`. In practice the `short` number of bits of the `int` are treated as the converted value: so here a `0xFFFF` pattern in a `short` means a `short` values of `-1` (we assume a regular two's complement signed representation).

Answer (score 0):

[The C99 language specification](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) says that "usual arithmetic conversions apply" when doing a bitwise AND, `val` is already an integer and the hex constant should be an integer too (see page 56) because it's the first type which can represent it. Both casting and assigning should truncate the `int` into a `short`, but you shouldn't lose any data in this case.

Comment: Thank you, that adds to the solution but I believe more can be added.

Answer (score 0):

`Val & 0x0000FFFF` is exactly the same as `Val & 0xFFFF`; both expressions have type `int`, and the result lies strictly in the range [0,65535].  (Assuming a 32-bit `int` type as stated by the questioner).

When you assign this result to a `short`, the value is unaltered if it is less than `SHRT_MAX`.  If it is greater than `SHRT_MAX` (which is probably 32767 on your platform), the behavior is implementation-defined[1].

If you assign the result instead to an `unsigned short`, which is required to be able to represent all possible values that can result from your expression, then the result will be fully specified by the standard.

---

1. In practice, on *nearly* all modern systems the result will be simply what you get from interpreting those 16 bits as a `short`, which is probably what you expect.

Comment: Would you mind commenting on what would have been the behavior had Val be been an unsigned int (32) ?

Comment: If Val is an unsigned int, then `Val & 0xFFFF` is also unsigned, but still lies in the same range [0,65535]; the behavior is identical.